# How to phrase these sentence grammatically?

Tags: clauses

Sentence:

> I returned my laptop to same courier, **which I received from them few months back**,
> so they picked the laptop from me on Oct 10 2022.

I have trouble phrasing this sentence because of this clause "**which I received from them**"

Comment: Do you mean "the same courier who delivered the laptop a few months back"? I'm not sure what "so they picked from me" means.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you mean "the same courier who delivered the laptop a few months back"? - **YES**

Comment: @KateBunting I made changes to it.

Comment: I'm unsure by what you mean by the verb "phrase". Do you mean "parse" (i.e., you are trying to understand a sentence that someone else has written) or "write" (i.e., you are creating the sentence)?

Comment: **The courier which I received from them** doesn't make sense. You received the laptop, not the courier. That's why I changed it to **the courier who delivered the laptop**. They **picked it up** from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I returned my laptop to same courier, which I received from them few
> months back, so they picked the laptop from me on Oct 10 2022.

If I am getting you correctly, you need to restructure your sentence a little and use new/proper verbs and add a few details.

> I **initiated** the return of my laptop "**on**" (insert the date of
> initiation of the return procedure), the same courier that
> **delivered** the laptop to me picked up the laptop from me on Oct 10, 2022.
>
> e.g. I initiated the return of my laptop on Xxx XX, XXXX; the same
> courier that delivered the laptop to me, picked up the laptop from me on Oct
> 10, 2022.

Or the shorter version

> I initiated the return of my laptop on Xxx XX, XXXX; the same courier
> that delivered the laptop, picked it up on Oct 10, 2022.

If you want to use "received" rather than "delivered", the sentence would look like

> I initiated the return of my laptop on Xxx XX, XXXX; the same courier
> that **I received the laptop from**, picked it up on Oct 10, 2022.

Hope this solves your problem with the sentence. Ordinarily proof-reading is off-topic on this forum. Moderators do however occasionally make exceptions.